# Defining a unified terminologies for a product?

Tags: documentation

When my team works on a project they usually come up with multiple names for the same thing. For example, if we have an Apartment entity, you might find some referring to it as an Apartment and others referring to it as a Flat. And so you see different names for the same thing in documents, database, code, and interfaces. I'm usually trying in the beginning of a project to force the idea of having a document to define unified terminologies for the team to stick with it. I'm wondering is there a known practice for something like that?

Comment: Let me share what a consultant at a previous company told me. "In programming tautology is not frowned upon. It is COMPULSORY". Here's another [quote](https://www.se.rit.edu/~tabeec/RIT_441/Resources_files/How%20To%20Write%20Unmaintainable%20Code.pdf): "use slightly different names for ... variables"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for [Ubiquitous Language](https://thedomaindrivendesign.io/developing-the-ubiquitous-language/) from [Domain Driven Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215).

> Ubiquitous Language is modeled within a Limited context, where the terms and concepts of the business domain are identified, and there should be no ambiguity.